# How to show animation only once per applicaton run (Android)?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I have 2 activities in my app:

- Activity 1 (with some elements) and
- Activity 2 which has Progress Bar (and the user needs to move between those all the time)

I want to show this progress bar in only the first time the user moves to the activity 2, every time the app launches (meaning if the app was closed and reopened and the user switched to activity 2, I want to show this progress bar again). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences. So, the SharedPreference can store a value of false by default. Whenever the app launches the SharedPreference has a value of false. And you get the value of the SharedPreference whenever activity 2 is launched. So if the value is false, you show the animation else not. Set the value of the SharedPreference to true when the animation is shown once. And set it back to false when on activity 1's onDestroy()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two different approaches

1. create static variable

   private static boolean showDialog = true;

   if (showDialog) {
   //   showProgress
   showDialog = false;
   }
2. Create not static flag

   private boolean showDialog = true;
   if (showDialog) {
   //   showProgress
   showDialog = false;
   }

and in activity onDestroy method drop flag value.

Comment: problem is the user keeps switching between activities, and then the onDestroy sets it on true again every time he witches activity and the bar is shown again, i used your first method without the onDestroy part and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use sharedPrefrence call sharedPref to check if progressbar shown before or not

```
  SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(" SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME ", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
```

and then depend on result set new value for sharedpref object

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("isProgressBarShown", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sp.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("isProgressBarShown", true);
ed.commit();
```